# How to put a loop in a switch statement

Tags: c++

I can't seem to figure out how to loop back to the selection if the value is invalid. Currently making a currency conversion calculator. Can't seem to make the terminal let the user input another number so they could convert freely. Thnx in advance!

```
int main()
{
    int value;
    cout << "Please select your conversion." << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 to convert PHP to US Dollars" << endl;
    cout << "Press 2 to convert PHP to GBP (Pound Sterling)" << endl;
    cout << "Press 3 to convert US Dollars to PHP" << endl;
    cout << "Press 4 to convert GBP (Pound Sterling) to PHP" << endl;
    
    cin>>value;
    /* test loop
    while (int value > 4) {
        cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
        cout << "Please input another number." << endl;
        }
    */
    float amount;
    float result;
    
    switch (value){
    case 1:
        cout << "Enter PHP Value: ";
        cin >> amount;
        result=amount*0.020;
        cout << amount << " PHP = " << result <<
    "USD";
    
    break;
    
    case 2:
        cout << "Enter PHP Value: ";
        cin >> amount;
        result=amount*0.014;
        cout << amount << " PHP = " << result << " GBP";
    
    break;
    
    case 3:
        cout << "Enter USD Value: ";
        cin >> amount;
        result=amount*51.27;
        cout << amount << " USD = " << result << " PHP";
    break;
    
    case 4:
        cout << "Enter GBP (Pound Sterling) Value: ";
        cin >> amount;
        result=amount*69.57;
        cout << amount << " GBP = " << result << " PHP";
    
    break;
    
    default:
        cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
        cout << "Please input another number." << endl;
        break;
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't want to put a loop in the `switch` - your want the reverse i.e. place the `switch` in the loop.   In the `switch` ensure the loop condition remains true if an invalid value is found.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything in a while loop as such:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while (true) // While loop
    {
        int value;
        std::cout << "Please select your conversion." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press 1 to convert PHP to US Dollars" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press 2 to convert PHP to GBP (Pound Sterling)" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press 3 to convert US Dollars to PHP" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press 4 to convert GBP (Pound Sterling) to PHP" << std::endl;

        std::cin >> value;
        /* test loop
    while (int value > 4) {
        std::cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
        std::cout << "Please input another number." << endl;
        }
    */
        float amount;
        float result;

        switch (value) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Enter PHP Value: ";
            std::cin >> amount;
            result = amount * 0.020;
            std::cout << amount << " PHP = " << result <<
                "USD";

            break;

        case 2:
            std::cout << "Enter PHP Value: ";
            std::cin >> amount;
            result = amount * 0.014;
            std::cout << amount << " PHP = " << result << " GBP";

            break;

        case 3:
            std::cout << "Enter USD Value: ";
            std::cin >> amount;
            result = amount * 51.27;
            std::cout << amount << " USD = " << result << " PHP";
            break;

        case 4:
            std::cout << "Enter GBP (Pound Sterling) Value: ";
            std::cin >> amount;
            result = amount * 69.57;
            std::cout << amount << " GBP = " << result << " PHP";

            break;

        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid Input." << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Please input another number." << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl; // Add this line to skip an extra line (for looks)
    }
    // Removed 'return 0;'
}
```

Also, don't use the following in your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

...as it's considered as bad practice. Type out std:: everytime instead.

Also consider refactoring your code by moving the code inside the while loop to a new function as such:

```
#include <iostream>

bool currency_conversion()
{
    int value;
    std::cout << "Please select your conversion." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press 1 to convert PHP to US Dollars" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press 2 to convert PHP to GBP (Pound Sterling)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press 3 to convert US Dollars to PHP" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press 4 to convert GBP (Pound Sterling) to PHP" << std::endl;

    std::cin >> value;
    /* test loop
while (int value > 4) {
    std::cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
    std::cout << "Please input another number." << endl;
    }
*/
    float amount;
    float result;

    switch (value) {
    case 1:
        std::cout << "Enter PHP Value: ";
        std::cin >> amount;
        result = amount * 0.020;
        std::cout << amount << " PHP = " << result <<
            "USD";

        break;

    case 2:
        std::cout << "Enter PHP Value: ";
        std::cin >> amount;
        result = amount * 0.014;
        std::cout << amount << " PHP = " << result << " GBP";

        break;

    case 3:
        std::cout << "Enter USD Value: ";
        std::cin >> amount;
        result = amount * 51.27;
        std::cout << amount << " USD = " << result << " PHP";
        break;

    case 4:
        std::cout << "Enter GBP (Pound Sterling) Value: ";
        std::cin >> amount;
        result = amount * 69.57;
        std::cout << amount << " GBP = " << result << " PHP";

        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Invalid Input." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Please input another number." << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    while (currency_conversion()) { /* Loop */ }
}
```

Anytime you wish to exit the application, return false from the currency_conversion function.

Comment: Hi! I'm kind of new to programming so I can't seem to figure out why use 'std'. Also how can i prompt the user to end the loop?

Comment: I am using std because it's considered a good practice to use namespace names every time as I mentioned in the answer. But the reason for that is for example you have 2 namespaces (namespaces are just containers of code) named n1 and n2 respectively, and both of them have a common function named print. Now if you add the lines 'using namespace n1' and 'using namespace n2', then use the print function somewhere in your program, the compiler won't be able to figure out which print function to use, i. e. n1::print or n2::print. Thus to avoid these situations, we should not use 'using namespace'.

Comment: I hope the explanation is clear :).

Answer (score 0):

This is working,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int value;
    do{
    cout << "Please select your conversion." << endl;
    cout << "Press 1 to convert PHP to US Dollars" << endl;
    cout << "Press 2 to convert PHP to GBP (Pound Sterling)" << endl;
    cout << "Press 3 to convert US Dollars to PHP" << endl;
    cout << "Press 4 to convert GBP (Pound Sterling) to PHP" << endl;

    cin>>value;
    /* test loop
while (int value > 4) {
    cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
    cout << "Please input another number." << endl;
    }
*/
    float amount;
    float result;

    switch (value){
case 1:
    cout << "Enter PHP Value: ";
    cin >> amount;
    result=amount*0.020;
    cout << amount << " PHP = " << result <<"USD";
     break;

case 2:
    cout << "Enter PHP Value: ";
    cin >> amount;
    result=amount*0.014;
    cout << amount << " PHP = " << result << " GBP";
    break;

case 3:
    cout << "Enter USD Value: ";
    cin >> amount;
    result=amount*51.27;
    cout << amount << " USD = " << result << " PHP";
    break;

case 4:
    cout << "Enter GBP (Pound Sterling) Value: ";
    cin >> amount;
    result=amount*69.57;
    cout << amount << " GBP = " << result << " PHP";

    break;

default:
    cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;
    cout << "Please input another number." << endl;
    break;

    }
    }while(value !=0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only add a switch case of zero,